# Using setState to toggle collapse and expand a row

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked a million times but all answers are the same and for some reason doesn't work for me. I'm sure someone has a good solution for this already as this is so common.

I have a simple render function that does

```
return(
            <div>
                <p className="profile-category" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>{this.props.title}:<Glyphicon glyph={opened ? "menu-up" : "menu-down"}/></p>
                <Collapse in={opened}>
                    <div>
                        <p>some components that are not important</p>
                    </div>
                </Collapse>
            </div>
        )
```

and I have the `handleOnClick` function as

```
  handleOnClick() {
    console.log('previous open: ', this.state.open)

    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        open: !this.state.open
    }), console.log('new state for open: ', this.state.open));
```

this is just one iteration of what I've tried. I've also tried `open: !prevState.open`, and inline setState like `onClick={this.setState({open: !this.state.open})}`

The toggle in the `<p>` works just fine, but the `<Collapse>` doesn't have the state up to date. I know `setState` is async, but having a callback (the console.log) should solve this problem, no?

Ultimately, how can I ensure the state in `<Collapse>` is up to date?

EDIT:

turns out I have bootstrap 4 installed, which react-bootstrap doesn't support. check your package.json to make sure bootstrap version is 3.

Comment: Is this `Collapse` from `Material-UI`?

Comment: `Collapse` is from React-bootstrap, sorry. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/#transitions-collapse

Comment: Unfamiliar with `react-bootstrap`, but you might want to take a second to make sure you understand how to pass functions.  Right now in both the second argument of `setState` and in the inline example you're not passing code to be executed at a later time.  You're executing code immediately and passing the return value of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you initialize open in state (constructor) after that try to change your `handleOnClick` function like this:

```
 onClick={() => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things could go wrong in your case. First, make sure your function is bound to your class, or use an arrow function.

Then, you are using the callback version of the `setState` function but are not using the previous state :

```
handleOnClick = event => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ open: !prevState.open }))
}
```

And if you want your `console.log` to print out the correct updated value, you will have to put in in a function, rather than executing it directly, as the second argument of `setState` is a callback :

```
handleOnClick = event => {
    this.setState(
        prevState => ({ open: !prevState.open }),
        () => { console.log(this.state.open) }
    )
}
```

Comment: I start thinking it's bootstrap's problem...... i've done some experiment like `this.state.open ? "open" : "close"` and the state is always correct. Maybe some css issue is preventing it from showing?